# PHP form handling not working with javascript onclick function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to submit a form, but before that, i want a javascript function to take place. Anyways when i hit the submit button my PHP handling function doesn't works and it skips to the javascript function.
How can i execute the PHP function and then the javascript ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Complete a survey to become part of our team.</title>

<!-- Start of content locker code -->

      <script type="text/javascript">var gwloaded = false;</script>
  <script src="http://asmlk.com/gwjs.php?aff=38757&prf=23145&sub1=" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">if (gwloaded == false) {
      window.location = "http://asmlk.com/widget_adblock.php?p=38757";
    }</script>
  <noscript>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://asmlk.com/widget_nojs.php?p=38757"/>
  </noscript>


<!-- End of content locker code -->

</head>
<body>
      <?php
        $userErr ="";
        $emailErr ="";

        $url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        if (strpos($url, 'error=user-empty') !== false) {
            $userErr ="Please enter your username!";

        }

        if (strpos($url, 'error=email-empty') !== false) {
            $emailErr ="Please enter your email!";
                echo $emailErr;
        }

        if (strpos($url, 'error=email-incorrect') !== false) {
            $emailErr ="Please enter a valid email!";
                echo $emailErr;
        }
        if (strpos($url, 'error=succes') !== false) {
            $entry = 'You have entered succesfully!';       
        }

      ?>
<h1> Please enter the following info: </h1>

<form method="post" action="enter.php">

Username: <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" /> <br>

<span class="error"><?php echo $userErr ?></span><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" /><br>
<span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr ?></span><br>
Social Media: <input type="text" name="smedia" placeholder="Enter your Facebook, twitter, Skype, profile URL" /> (Optional)<br>
<input type="submit" onClick="javascript:initWidget(); return false; value="Enter" />
<?php echo $entry ?>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

If i would run the code above, normally when i click the Enter button the PHP validation works, once i add the OnClick function it doesnt works anymore.

Comment: Where is ``initWidget`` defined? did you check your console to see if you got an error because of calling an undefined function?

Comment: I updated my code, InitWidget its a content locker widget.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Add `id` to your form:

```
<form method="post" action="enter.php" id="myForm">
```

Attach the javascript form submit method to your button:

```
<input type="submit" onClick="javascript:initWidget();document.getElementById('myForm').submit();" value="Enter" />
```

This way your `onClick` method might not override the browser submit action.

Comment: This one kinda worked, it made the PHP validation work but in the end my widget didn't show at all, and the form was submitted without the user completing the widged.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the event handler on `submit` event

```
<form method="post" action="enter.php" onsubmit="return !!initWidget();">
```

and instead of explicitly returning `false` you can return Boolean representation of whatever value `initWidget` returned.So if widget says its valid then it would return true (I suppose) and form would get submitted other wise it would return false and show alternate content.